# Read stderr after manually terminating a process

Tags: python

For using `subprocess` python module, 
I know that using `communicate()` is the right approach to read `stdout` and `stderr`.

However, my situation is slightly different from the cases I surveyed from internet.

In my situation, I use `subprocess.Popen` to run an executable that it doesn't terminate itself. 
This is what I did:

```
import signal
import subprocess as subp

exe = subp.Popen([the_exe, the_arg], shell=False, stdout=subp.PIPE, stderr=subp.PIPE) 

# one minute later...     

exe.send_signal(signal.SIGINT) 
pipe_stdout, pipe_stderr = exe.communicate()
```

But I still got deadlock on the call of `communicate()`... 
I am using python3.

I also tried replacing `send_signal(signal.SIGINT)` with `exe.terminate()` or `exe.kill()`. 
But none of the above solved the problem...

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.4 on Ubuntu. What program are you running, and are you sure that the program is terminating (i.e. not catching `SIGINT`)?

Comment: The executable `the_exe` was designed to run for a long time. But I only need the message it writes to `stderr` in the first few minutes...